# Ruby on Rails: Modern development good practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I am planning to build a web app with the Ruby on Rails framework. 
In the future, the web app might need to evolve into an iOS or Android app.

I am wondering what's the best practice is to structure the software so that it can be easily migrated to different platforms.

Comment: You'll need to read several books on this subject. This is not answerable in one short post.

Answer (score 3):

Use Rails only for backend, build some API server. For frontend you can use anything you want: web(angular, reactjs, other js), ios app, android app.